# Show/hide toggle, and adding classes

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an FAQ page.

I want to toggle the answers open and closed. I have that working using jquery.

I also want to add a class (.active) to the selector that is "open". I can add the class to the parent.

My problem is this: I need to use unclassed elements, because the end-user will not understand adding classes. It needs to be un-styled block elements. So it looks like this:

```
<h3 class="active">Activator</h3>
  <p>show</p>
<h3>Activator</h3>
  <p>hide</p>
<h3>Activator</h3>
  <p>hide</p>
etc...
```

When the script adds the class .active to the h3 that is clicked, it adds the class .active to ALL the h3 tags.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content p').hide();
    $('h3').click(function(){
        $(this).next("p").toggle(250);
    });
    $(".content h3").click(function(){
        $(".content h3").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Link: [working demo/site](http://www.wo.redpointdesign.ca/about/faq/)
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are selecting all the elements in your `click` handler with `$(".content h3")`.  Instead, you need to reference `this` to get just the element that was clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content p').hide();
    $('h3').click(function(){
        $(this).next("p").toggle(250);
    });
    $(".content h3").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

**Edit:** A nice trick would be to set up your CSS like this:

```css
.content p
{
    display: none;
}
.content h3.active + p
{
    display: block;
}
```

By using the adjacent sibling combinator (`+`) you control the display of the `<p>` based on whether your `<h3>` is active.  You can then simplify your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content h3").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

You lose your animation this way, but then you could add it back in with a CSS3 transition.

**Edit:** Transitioning height is tricky if the height is not fixed.  It can be accomplished by transitioning `max-height`, but when collapsing, there can be a delay.  You can play with the values to get something that works pretty well.  Here's what I came up with: [jsfiddle.net/FsVPn](http://jsfiddle.net/FsVPn/)

Comment: Thank you very much!! I don't know javascript well at all (as it would seem)

Comment: I gave you +1 for the right answer - I'd give you another +1 for your edit if I could...